# llvm pass to flatten (some) nested loops

Tags: llvm, nested-loops

I want to automatically rewrite simple nested loops as non nested ones.
For example, I have the following code:

```
if (y >= 0)
{
    while (x>y)
    {
        x -= y+1;
        for (z=y; z>0; z--) /* nothing */;
    }
}
```

And I would like some **llvm magic** to happen so that it becomes:

```
if (y >= 0)
{
    bool outer = true;
    while (x>y)
    {
        if (outer) { z = y;                  }
        if (z > 0) { z--;     outer = false; }
        else       { x-= y+1; outer = true;  }
    }
}
```

Am I being over optimistic thinking such a pass exists?
I tried writing `opt --help > /tmp/passes.txt && grep "loop" /tmp/passes.txt`
but there are so many loop passes I don't know where to start.

Comment: You would like to have a pass that removes no-nop loops? Finding out whether any current passes do that should be simple, just run each pass in turn on input with a suitable body, and see which passes some line in the loop. One long sh line should do, along the lines of `for a in $(opt --help | awk '/      --/{print $1}') ; do opt $a … | grep -q … || echo $a ; done`

Comment: @arnt, what would be the pattern inside `grep -q ...`? How would I know that the inner loop no longer exists? what should I look for?

Comment: The pattern is one that matche a line inside the loop, for example the label of a relevant basic block. You control the input IR, so making a suitable name should be easy. grep -q || echo prints the name of the pass if that pattern (and by extension, that basic block) was removed by that pass.

Answer (score 2):

This optimization is called loop fusion. I haven't tried your code but Polly should be able to fuse such loops. Polly is the polyhedral compiler framework that ships with LLVM but it should build with LLVM by default. If it does not then you'd need to pass  `-DLLVM_POLLY_BUILD:BOOL=ON` to cmake to build polly with llvm.

Here's the documentation on how to invoke polly optimizations with clang/llvm.

https://polly.llvm.org/docs/UsingPollyWithClang.html#optimizing-with-polly